Additional information in SPF resinfo of Authentication-Results header
I am reading RFC 8601 and trying to understand the syntax of Authentication-Results header.
However, I am having trouble understanding the result of methodspec.
Below are the emails I received:

Example 1
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@spmail.uber.com header.s=scph header.b=SlxltaO2;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounce@spmail.uber.com designates 147.253.216.74 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=bounce@spmail.uber.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=uber.com

In the case above, the header can be broken down as below:

authserv-id : mx.google.com
authres-version : not indicated in the header
resinfo : three resinfo's in the header

resinfo (DKIM)

methodspec

method : dkim
result : pass


reasonspec : not indicated
propspec : header.i=@spmail.uber.com, header.s=scph, header.b=SlxltaO2


resinfo (SPF)

methodspec

method : spf
result : pass


reasonspec : not indicated
propspec : smtp.mailfrom=bounce@spmail.uber.com


resinfo (DMARC)

methodspec

method : dmarc
result : pass


reasonspec : not indicated
propspec : header.from=uber.com





Question:
What are (google.com: domain of bounce@spmail.uber.com designates 147.253.216.74 as permitted sender) and (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE)?
According to RFC 8601, RFC 5321 and RFC 5234, result of methodspec is defined as below.
So result of methodspec should only be alphabets, digits and -.
result = Keyword

Keyword = Ldh-str
Ldh-str = *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" ) Let-dig
Let-dig = ALPHA / DIGIT

ALPHA = %x41-5A / %x61-7A   ; A-Z / a-z
DIGIT = %x30-39             ; 0-9

I expected that they are part of result of methodspec, however, since (google.com: domain of bounce@spmail.uber.com designates 147.253.216.74 as permitted sender) and (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) contain symbols and whitespaces, they should not be result of methodspec.
I thought they may be reasonspec or propspec, however, they are not following the syntax of reasonspec and propspec.
resinfo is defined as [CFWS] ";" methodspec [ CFWS reasonspec ] [ CFWS 1*propspec ], and if they are not methodspec, reasonspec, or propspec, what are they ?  In which part of RFC are they defined ?
Answer (Thanks to @synchro):
Two texts (google.com: domain of bounce@spmail.uber.com designates 147.253.216.74 as permitted sender) and (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) are regarded as comment(CFWS), as they are defined as below in RFC 5322.
CFWS = (1*([FWS] comment) [FWS]) / FWS
comment = "(" *([FWS] ccontent) [FWS] ")"
ccontent = ctext / quoted-pair / comment
ctext = %d33-39 / %d42-91 / %d93-126 / obs-ctext ; Printable US-ASCII characters not including "(", ")", or "\"
quoted-pair = ("\" (VCHAR / WSP)) / obs-qp


Example 2
Authentication-Results = amazonses.com;
       spf=pass (spfCheck: domain of _spf.google.com designates 209.85.216.48 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.216.48; envelope-from=xxx.yyy@gmail.com; helo=mail-pj1-f48.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com;
       dmarc=pass header.from=gmail.com;

Received-SPF: pass (spfCheck: domain of _spf.google.com designates 209.85.216.48 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.216.48; envelope-from=xxx.yyy@gmail.com; helo=mail-pj1-f48.google.com;

In the case above, the resinfo of SPF is
spf=pass (spfCheck: domain of _spf.google.com designates 209.85.216.48 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.216.48; envelope-from=xxx.yyy@gmail.com; helo=mail-pj1-f48.google.com;

and I understand that there are two below:

methodspec : spf=pass
comment(CFWS) : (spfCheck: domain of _spf.google.com designates 209.85.216.48 as permitted sender)

According to RFC 7208, Received-SPF header is defined as below, thus client-ip=209.85.216.48; envelope-from=xxx.yyy@gmail.com; helo=mail-pj1-f48.google.com must be key-value-list of Received-SPF header-field.
header-field = "Received-SPF:" [CFWS] result FWS [comment FWS] [ key-value-list ] CRLF
result = "pass" / "fail" / "softfail" / "neutral" / "none" / "temperror" / "permerror"
key-value-list = key-value-pair *( ";" [CFWS] key-value-pair ) [";"]
key-value-pair = key [CFWS] "=" ( dot-atom / quoted-string )
key = "client-ip" / "envelope-from" / "helo" / "problem" / "receiver" / "identity" / "mechanism" / name
name = ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "_" / "." )

RFC 7208 (Section-9.2) also states that:

It is, however, possible to add CFWS in the "reason" part of an
Authentication-Results header field and provide the equivalent
information, if desired.
As an example, an expanded Authentication-Results header field
might    look like (for a "MAIL FROM" check in this example):
Authentication-Results: myhost.example.org; spf=pass
reason="client-ip=192.0.2.1; smtp.helo=foo.example.com"
smtp.mailfrom=user@example.net

Following this rule, key-value-list in Received-SPF header-field can be value of reasonspec in Authentication-Results header.
Question:
If I follow the RFC 7208, the SPF resinfo should have reasonspec like:
spf=pass (spfCheck: domain of _spf.google.com designates 209.85.216.48 as permitted sender) reason="client-ip=209.85.216.48; envelope-from=xxx.yyy@gmail.com; helo=mail-pj1-f48.google.com";

However, the email I received actually was this:
spf=pass (spfCheck: domain of _spf.google.com designates 209.85.216.48 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.216.48; envelope-from=xxx.yyy@gmail.com; helo=mail-pj1-f48.google.com;

The reasonspec is defined as "reason" [CFWS] "=" [CFWS] value, so reason= should not be omitted. Why is this happening ?

Elements in parentheses are comments, as per RFC5322 section 3.2.2, which RFC8601 inherits from:

Strings of characters enclosed in parentheses are considered comments

As such, they should be stripped from the header value before interpreting it, which is what RFC8601 section 2.1 is talking about when it says:

The value of the header field (after removing comments) consists of
an authentication service identifier, an optional version, and then a
series of statements and supporting data.

See also their "comment-heavy example" in appendix B7.
Note that comments can be nested, so be careful if you're trying to strip/extract them with regex, as the expression will need to be recursive.
Using your example, the header after stripping comments should look like this:
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@spmail.uber.com header.s=scph header.b=SlxltaO2;
       spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=bounce@spmail.uber.com;
       dmarc=pass header.from=uber.com

As far as I can see, the remaining text is a valid header: everything in it is ;, space or FWS delimited, and is in a key=value format. Remember that comments can occur anywhere in a header value, even right in the middle of a value (or even another comment), for example header.from=ub(comment)er.com is fine.
Regarding methodspec values, I don't see the issue - the value is pass, which is entirely valid. It's quite OK to have additional values in the prop spec. Section 2.1 says:

For each such
statement, the supporting data can include a "reason" string and one
or more "property=value" statements indicating which message
properties were evaluated to reach that conclusion.

This is why it's using [ CFWS 1*propspec ], which means "at least one propspec", but more is fine.
It doesn't say that all SPF propspecs have to be smtp type, but it does say:

Results reported using unknown ptypes MUST NOT be used in making
handling decisions.  They can be safely ignored by consumers.

suggesting they can be considered much like comments, except they are in a fixed format and thus parseable.
A nicely written question BTW!

Thank you for your answer. I was completely missing the comments syntax.
So the two parentheses in the question are the comments, and they should be the CFWS right before propspec in resinfo = [CFWS] ";" methodspec [ CFWS reasonspec ] [ CFWS 1*propspec ], since CFWS = (1*([FWS] comment) [FWS]) / FWS and  comment = "(" *([FWS] ccontent) [FWS] ")".

I also have another email sample whose Authentication-Results header contains a resinfo spf=pass (spfCheck: domain of _spf.google.com designates 209.85.216.48 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.216.48; envelope-from=xxx.yyy@gmail.com; helo=mail-pj1-f48.google.com;. In this case, (spfCheck: domain of _spf.google.com designates 209.85.216.48 as permitted sender) will also be the comments, but what about the text after the comments client-ip=209.85.216.48; envelope-from=xxx.yyy@gmail.com; helo=mail-pj1-f48.google.com; ? They are not in parentheses, so they cannot be the comments.

client-ip=209.85.216.48; envelope-from=xxx.yyy@gmail.com; helo=mail-pj1-f48.google.com; doesn't start from reason so it's not reasonspec, and it's not propspec because the syntax does not match propspec = ptype [CFWS] "." [CFWS] property [CFWS] "=" pvalue (also it's SPF resinfo, so ptype must be smtp).
